# Subquery for fetching table name

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, oracle, postgresql

I have a query like this :

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT linktable FROM adm_linkedfields WHERE name = 'company') as cbo WHERE group='BEST'
```

Basically, the table name for the main query is fetched through the subquery.

I get an error that `#1054 - Unknown column 'group' in 'where clause'`

When I investigate (removing the where clause), I find that the query only returns the subquery result at all times.

Subquery table `adm_linkedfields` has structure `id | name | linktable`

Currently am using MySQL with PDO but the query should be compatible with major DBs (viz. Oracle, MSSQL, PgSQL and MySQL)

**Update:**
The subquery should return the name of the table for the main query.  In this case it will return `tbl_company`

The table `tbl_company` for the main query has this structure :
`id | name | group`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: see my answer for the reason of error. BTW from where the column "group" came from..it's not in your table definition?? and it's a DT not SubQ.

Comment: Why down vote? Appreciate if there's a reason given.

Comment: @user2407394 he's calling "group" column in the WHERE clause but the subquery returns only one column called linktable.

Comment: @jakub: It's "DT" not subQ. He updated the question after my comment.. @ Ravi: Thanks for update. Now I understand what you want to do. I tend to agree with Jakub's answer. -1 was for lack of details. Removing it.

Answer (score 1):

Dynamic SQL doesn't work like that, what you created is an inline-view, read up on that. What's more, you can't create a dynamic sql query that will work on every db. If you have a limited number of linktables you could try using left-joins or unions to select from all tables but if you don't have a good reason you don't want that.
Just select the tablename in one query and then make another one to access the right table (by creating the query string in php).

Comment: Thanks Jakub. I just did that. Wanted to know if I can do it in a single query than making two calls.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an issue:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT linktable FROM adm_linkedfields WHERE name = 'company') as cbo 
WHERE group='BEST';
```

You are selecting from DT which contains only one column "linktable", then you cant put any other column in where clause of outer block. Think in terms of blocks the outer select is refering a DT which contains only one column.

Your problem is similar when you try to do:

```
create table t1(x1 int);
select * from t1 where z1 = 7;  //error
```

Comment: Thanks. I have my table name stored in another table (which am trying to fetch through subquery) and want to return all rows from that table. I have give my target table structure in the update if it might help.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT linktable
      FROM adm_linkedfields
      WHERE name = 'company'
     ) cbo
WHERE group='BEST'
```

First, if you are interested in cross-database compatibility, do not name columns or tables after SQL reserved words.  `group` is a really, really bad name for a column.

Second, the `from` clause is returning a table containing a list of names (of tables, but that is irrelevant).  There is no column called `group`, so that is the problem you are having.

What can you do to fix this?  A naive solution would be to run the subquery, run it, and use the resulting table name in a dynamic statement to execute the query you want.

The fundamental problem is your data structure.  Having multiple tables with the same structure is generally a sign of a bad design.  You basically have two choices.

One.  If you have control over the database structure, put all the data in a single table, `linktable` for instance.  This would have the information for all companies, and a column for `group` (or whatever you rename it).  This solution is compatible across all databases.  If you have lots and lots of data in the tables (think tens of millions of rows), then you might think about partitioning the data for performance reasons.

Two.  If you don't have control over the data, create a view that concatenates all the tables together.  Something like:

```
create view vw_linktable as
    select 'table1' as which, t.* from table1 t union all
    select 'table2', t.* from table2 t
```

This is also compatible across all databases.